# Validating newly created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

i have problem when i use input type file

the code is like this below,

default input file :

```
<div id="div_attachment">
   <input name="f_attachment[]" type="file" class="file" id="f_attachment">
   <input type="button" id="tb_more_files" value="more file"/>
</div>
```

and jquery code :

```
$("input#tb_more_files").click(function(){
   var new_file = $("<div><input id='f_attachment' name='f_attachment[]' type='file' class='file'/><input type='button' id='tb_remove' class='remove_file'></div>");
   $("div#div_attachment").append(new_file);
});
```

and i validate extension of attachment file with this :

```
f_attachment = $("input#f_attachment").val();
FileType = f_attachment.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

   if(f_attachment == null || f_attachment == ""){
       alert("Attachment is Empty");
   }else if($.inArray(FileType, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1){
       alert("Invalid Type of File Attachment");
   }
```

and the problem is, when i clicked more file button
and input file element is appear,
i cannot validate it when it have empty or null value or different file type validation!

i try with .live() method, but i dont know how...

please help!

Comment: You should consider using the `$.delegate()` instead of `$.live()`. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ - See `Additional Notes`

Comment: how to get value of new upload element with $.delegate() or $.live() method?

Comment: Just so you know, jQuery's `.live()` method [is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead: `$(document).on('click', 'input#tb_more_files', function () {...`

Comment: i am using form, 

`
$("form").submit(){
  //validation...
}
`

Comment: @JinSun I have updated your question title - you do not need to use live() here.

Comment: You should not create elements using the same `ID`. "f_attachment" and "tb_remove".

Comment: i think it is not matter, i just want to get value of new input file element... when it is null, alert it and focusing on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a complete fiddle for you; http://jsfiddle.net/7KLA6/

**UPDATE** Adding the code on request

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">

<div id="div_attachment">
   <input name="f_attachment[]" type="file" class="file" id="f_attachment">
   <input type="button" id="tb_more_files" value="Add extra file" />
</div>

<input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit form" />

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Add file input
$("input#tb_more_files").click(function() {

    var new_file = $("<div><input name='f_attachment[]' type='file' class='file'/><input type='button' class='remove_file' value='Remove' /></div>");
    $("div#div_attachment").append(new_file);

});

// Remove added file input
$('#div_attachment').on('click', 'input.remove_file', function() {

    $(this).parent().remove();

});

// Validate on submit
$('form').submit(function() {

    var $form = $(this);
    var validForm = true;

    $form.find('input.file').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var fileName = $this.val();
        var fileType = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

        if (fileName == null || fileName == "") {
            console.log("Attachment is Empty"); // DEBUG
            validForm = false;
        } else if ($.inArray(fileType, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
            console.log("Invalid Type of File Attachment"); // DEBUG
            validForm = false;
        }

        if (!validForm) {
            $this.css('color', 'red').focus();
            // Notice that only the last input will get the focus.
        }
    });

    console.log('Valid form =', validForm); // DEBUG
    return validForm;
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that solve the problem here, we can't count on jsFiddle to exist forever.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#div_attachment').on("change",".file", function(event) {
  value = $(this).val(); // the value of the file element
  // do validation
});
```

this listens to the `change` event on all elements with the class `file` within the element `div_attachment` (your parent div) and processes your validation. Using `on()` means that even newly created DOM elements will have the event handler applied

One thing you need to be careful of is using the same ID for multiple elements - you are better using a class.

### Update

To perform the check `onsubmit()` use the `each()` method :

```
$('.file').each(function(index) {
    value = $(this).val();
    // some validation for $(this) using value
});
```

NOTE: Using the `$('.file')` selector gets all the elements with the class `file`

[Docs for each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/),
[Docs for on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: `if(value == null || value == ""){
alert("New Attachment is Empty");
}else{
return true;
}`

its still not working!

Comment: @JinSun What doesnt work ? `alert` or `console.log` value - is if the correct value

Comment: @JinSun to check for empty value you can use `if($(this).val()) { // something there } else { empty }`

Comment: i try to focus on new file element when it has null value,
alerting is okay, but focus on it, has not working..

Comment: i think it is not matter, i just want to get value of new input file element... when it is null, alert it and focusing on it!

Comment: i found the problem,
i not put return false after alerting,
and not put $(this).focus()

thats all..

thx for your help..

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" onsubmit="return  validateForm()" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="browse" name="browse" size="" placeholder="Photo" class="upload"/>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["browse"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
      //do somthing
        return false;
    } else {
      //do somthing
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: no, i mean when new file upload appeared, i need to validate it!

Comment: note :

i am using form :

`$("form").submit(){
 //validation...
}`

Comment: i think it is not matter, i just want to get value of new input file element... when it is null, alert it and focusing on it!

Comment: ...and if there are more than one `input` without a selected file?

Comment: yes, more than one input...
i have input text and input file,
nad the problem is when validating add more input file element